# How to combine two lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have two lists:

```
l1 = list(2, 3)
l2 = list(4)
```

I want a third list:

```
list(2, 3, 4).
```

How can I do it in simple way.
Although I can do it in for loop, but I am expecting a one liner answer, or maybe an in-built method.

Actually, I have a list:
`list(list(2, 3), list(2, 4), list(3, 5), list(3, 7), list(5, 6), list(5, 7), list(6, 7)).`
After computing on `list(2, 3)` and `list(2, 4)`, I want `list(2, 3, 4)`.

Comment: `c(l1, l2)`? if you expect something else, could you please detail a bit and/or share your lists and the desired output?

Comment: It's of the same format as I have provided above.

Comment: I have a list: list(list(2, 3), list(2, 4), list(3, 5), list(3, 7), list(5, 6), list(5, 7), list(6, 7)). After computing on list(2, 3) and list(2, 4), I want list(2, 3, 4). That's it.

Comment: Thanks @Hadd E. Nuff. It works for my purpose. I though it just concatenates vectors, not lists. You may post it as answer if you want..

Comment: @Vincent got here first.  It's his answer.

Comment: From your edit: if you have `list(2, 3)` and `list(2, 4),` and want `list(2, 3, 4)`, you may also want `unique(c(l1, l2))`

Comment: @RohitSingh if you want me to turn it into an answer let me know; otherwise, mayeb you can just close it?

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Bonhomme. I see you have already gave me the answer but I thought you wanted clarification. Yeah Vincent please give it as answer.

Comment: Thanks @user20650 but I didn't want unique. I wanted all elements of l1 and last element of l2. It's actually related to Apriori algorithm in data mining.

Comment: @Vincent Bonhomme turn in the answer please.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

`c` can be used on lists (and not only on vectors):

```
# you have
l1 = list(2, 3)
l2 = list(4)

# you want
list(2, 3, 4)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4

# you can do
c(l1, l2)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 4
```

If you have a list of lists, you can do it (perhaps) more comfortably with `do.call`, eg:

```
do.call(c, list(l1, l2))
```

Comment: How could this code be applied to n lists? Let's say I have 100 lists and want to combine them using c(). Could I do this without writing ```c(l1, l2, l3, l4...l100```?

Comment: @NorthLattitude when creating lists, there must be a way to put all lists within a list ;-).  Otherwise, that's still feasible with `parse/eval`, ie: ```l1 <- "a"; l2 <- "b" ; l3 <- "c"; 
eval(parse(text=paste0("list(", paste0("l", 1:3, collapse = ", "), ")")))```

Answer (score 78):

We can use `append`

```
append(l1, l2)
```

It also has arguments to insert element at a particular location.

Comment: @Zach `paste` and `paste0` are to join strings together to a  bigger string.  Can you describe the problem a bit more as I didn't understand it clearly?

Comment: @akrun How is the syntax for more than two lists?

Comment: @Frosi you can do `c(l1, l2, l3)`, `append()` is just a wrapper for `c()` but only takes two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth a mention of utils::modifyList. This merges two lists by keys (which your example doesn't include).

```
> l1 = list(a=2, b=3)
> l2 = list(b=4, c=5)
> modifyList(l1, l2)
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 4

$c
[1] 5
```

Answer (score -1):

`l1=list(2,3) l2=list(3,4) l3=unique(c(l1,l2))`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -3):

I was looking to do the same thing, but to preserve the list as a just an array of strings so I wrote a new code, which from what I've been reading may not be the most efficient but worked for what i needed to do:

```
combineListsAsOne <-function(list1, list2){
  n <- c()
  for(x in list1){
    n<-c(n, x)
  }
  for(y in list2){
    n<-c(n, y)
  }
  return(n)
}
```

It just creates a new list and adds items from two supplied lists to create one.

Comment: Mods I think this can be deleted. Thanks.