# Maintaining names while flattening lists in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, names

Below is some dummy data and code. I think I'm trying to do the exact opposite to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767056/combine-list-and-element-from-2nd-list-while-maintaining-names-in-r)

After manipulating for [a statistical test](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvequality/vignettes/how_to_test_CVs.html), I'm left with a very ugly looking list. When I unpack this list [as per this method with `unlist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674661/r-list-of-lists-to-data-frame), the variable/country coding stored in names is totally lost.

I would like to have a data frame with countries as row names and categories as column names.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

```
set.seed(1)

CVtest <- list()

for (i in c("AT","BE","DE")) { #For all countries

  # Test all categories together

  CVtest[[i]][["EveryCat"]] <-  sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 1)

    for (j in c("All", "Sub", "Key", "Sel")) { # Test each category

      CVtest[[i]][[j]] <- sample(seq(0, 1, by=0.01), 1)
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
> class(CVtest)
[1] "list"
> CVtest

$`AT` EveryCat      All      Sub      Key      Sel 
    0.26     0.37     0.57     0.91     0.20 

$BE EveryCat      All      Sub      Key      Sel 
    0.90     0.95     0.66     0.63     0.06 

$DE EveryCat      All      Sub      Key      Sel 
    0.20     0.17     0.69     0.38     0.77
```

Desired output

```
> class(CVtest)
[1] "data.frame"
> CVtest
       EveryCat  All  Sub  Key  Sel
AT     0.26 0.37 0.57 0.91 0.20
BE     0.90 0.95 0.66 0.63 0.06
DE     0.20 0.17 0.69 0.38 0.77
```

Comment: Can't you do a minimal example ? You provide some code but it is lengthy and it requires to install some packages.

Comment: Sorry, that should be it. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You don't provide `df` in your post. And the index `i` of the loop is not used. Also, could you show the desired output?

Comment: sorry again, `i` was indeed meant to replace `df`... forgot about that bit. Now fixed including desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still not clear (see my latest comment). I can only guess what you want. Could you try:

```
x <- purrr::transpose(CVtest)
y <- rlist::list.stack(x)
rownames(y) <- names(x)
y
```

Say me whether `y` is the desired output. Otherwise I will delete this answer and please clarify your question.

Comment: I fixed the code and other parts of the question; I believe it's quite clear right now. Thanks for your patience. Your solution does the job, I wanted to have countries as rows, so I just added t(y). Thank you very much!!