# Break a column of lists into several columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column which contains lists of two numbers. I'd like to break it into 2 columns. I found a convoluted solution, but was hoping someone could improve on it.

My solution:

```
column=list(c(1,2),c(3,4))

cols = list(1,length(column[[1]]))

# given a list, return the ith element
f = function(l, i) {
  return(l[i])
}
# apply function f to each column 
g = function(i) {
  sapply(column, f, i)
}
# for each column ...
sapply(cols, g)
```

This gives the desired output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    3    4
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind,column)`

Comment: I figured there had to be a 1 liner. Thanks a bunch. Post as answer and ill accept.

Comment: Thanks, but no need to transform it to an answer since it  has answered many times. There exists some duplicate in somewhere i.e [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665492/how-to-combine-two-lists-in-r) one.

Comment: ah ok. somehow i didn't find those