# R fuse several JSON

Tags: r, json

i'm having struggle to make a JSON from several different JSON in R. I'm making a request to an API while increasing the final parameter in function of the var "individus". For each request i receive a JSON and i only keep the "$top" part of it.

```
for (i in 1:individus){
    url_req <- paste("api_url", i, sep="")
    list_json1 <- fromJSON(url_req)

    if (missing(list_json1) == TRUE){
        inter_json <- list_json1$top
    }else{
        inter_json <- inter_json+list_json1$top
    }
}
```

My question is how can i fuse those data in a single json a little bit like that :

```
inter_json <- inter_json+list_json1$top
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing the concat-operators: `+` is used in javscript but not in R. Since the object returned by `fromJSON` is a list, you need to combine lists and could have a look here: [how-to-combine-two-lists-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665492/how-to-combine-two-lists-in-r)