# How to Effectively Join Two Lists Elementwise by Element Name

Tags: r, list, join

I wonder if there is an effective (without loops) method of joining two lists by names of their elements.
I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36665492/5043424) but this did not help me as well as tried to access names from `sapply()` as on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36665492/5043424).

Say I have the following lists:

```
mylist1 <- list(region1 = 1:3, region2 = 5:7)
> mylist1
$region1
[1] 1 2 3

$region2
[1] 5 6 7
```

and

```
mylist2 <- list(region1 = "#E8C506", region2 = "#F3B508")
$region1
[1] "#E8C506"

$region2
[1] "#F3B508"
```

How can I get joined list by element names:

```
mylist3 <- list(region1 = list(1:3, "#E8C506"), region2 = list(5:7, "#F3B508"))
> mylist3
$region1
$region1[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$region1[[2]]
[1] "#E8C506"


$region2
$region2[[1]]
[1] 5 6 7

$region2[[2]]
[1] "#F3B508"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying heavily on the answers from @Ajar and @Flodel to [Combine/merge lists by elements names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57171812/4786466), this maps into `list`'s instead of a vectors (`c`) to achieve your end:

Using `base`:

```r
keys <- unique(c(names(mylist1), names(mylist2)))
setNames(mapply(list, mylist1[keys], mylist2[keys], SIMPLIFY = FALSE), keys)
```

Using `purrr`:

```r
library(purrr)

cat_lists <- function(list1, list2) {  

  keys <- unique(c(names(list1), names(list2)))
  map2(list1[keys], list2[keys], list) |>
    set_names(keys)  

}

reduce(list(mylist1, mylist2), cat_lists)
```

Output:

```
$region1
$region1[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$region1[[2]]
[1] "#E8C506"


$region2
$region2[[1]]
[1] 5 6 7

$region2[[2]]
[1] "#F3B508"
```

Answer (score 3):

If the elements are identical in both lists you can use `purrr::transpose()`:

```
library(purrr)

transpose(list(mylist1, mylist2))

$region1
$region1[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$region1[[2]]
[1] "#E8C506"


$region2
$region2[[1]]
[1] 5 6 7

$region2[[2]]
[1] "#F3B508"
```

Note `tranpose()` uses the first list as a template and matches subsequent list elements by name, so if the elements are different across lists, you need to ensure all names are first present in the first list, e.g.:

```
mylist3 <- list(region1 = 1:3, region2 = 5:7, region3 = 5:7)
mylist4 <- list(region1 = "#E8C506", region2 = "#F3B508", region4 = "#F00008")

l <- list(mylist3, mylist4)
l_names <- unique(unlist(lapply(l, names)))
mylist3[l_names] <- mylist3[l_names]

transpose(list(mylist3, mylist4))

$region1
$region1[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$region1[[2]]
[1] "#E8C506"


$region2
$region2[[1]]
[1] 5 6 7

$region2[[2]]
[1] "#F3B508"


$region3
$region3[[1]]
[1] 5 6 7

$region3[[2]]
NULL


$region4
$region4[[1]]
NULL

$region4[[2]]
[1] "#F00008"
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked with `bench`. Your code is most effective

Answer (score 1):

I hope this works.

```
list12 <- mapply(list, mylist1 , mylist2 , SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: The code is giving wrong output for mismatched list names see: `list(region1 = 1:3, region2 = 5:7, region3 = 5:7)` and `list(region1 = "#E8C506", region2 = "#F3B508", region4 = "#F00008")`